# Is there any way to deploy front end code inside s3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, web-deployment

Is there any way to deploy front end code (html, static files) inside s3 bucket like apache deployment?

Comment: Yes, if they are static pages. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer you put your files in an S3 bucket and then you direct the traffic towards this bucket with the Route53 Service.